# Need input on calculated field formula with if else condition in AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

So, I have a use case where I need to calculate the monthly costs of my clients Quicksight usage.
If the user has an 'Author' role the cost is fixed to 18$ per month. If the user has 'Reader' access, it costs 0.30cents for 30 minutes for the first 17 sessions and 5$ fixed rate if the usage exceeds 17 sessions.(How I calculated the number of sessions is another story).
So, say I have a visual like this:
[image]

I redacted the user names for obvious reasons. I just want to add a simple calculated field called total_cost with following code:

```
    ifelse(role = 'Author', 18,ifelse(role = 'Reader' AND {total_sessions_per_month} >= 17, 5,ifelse(role = 'Reader' AND {total_sessions_per_month} < 17, 0.30*{total_sessions_per_month}
, 0)))
```

I am getting a syntax error with this code. It says, `"The syntax of the calculated field expression is incorrect. Correct the syntax and choose Create again."`

Also, I am not entirely sure about the logic of the code here, as the field 'total_sessions_per_month' is another aggregated field.

```
sumOver(sum({total_sessions}),[{user_name},role,year,month])
```

I don't know how it fits here, as I formed a condition with an non-aggregated field(role) and aggregated field(total_sessions_per_month).

I hope someone can help me figure this out, as I am pretty new to Quicksight and BI in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifelse(role = 'Author', 18, (role = reader AND {total_sessions_per_month} >= 17), 5, (role = reader AND {total_sessions_per_month} < 17, 0.3 * total_sessions_per_month, ELSE)
```

Have a look at : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/ifelse-function.html